# Is there a way to pass a parameter to sublime text3 insert snippet using tab trigger?

Tags: sublimetext, code-snippets, sublimetext4

Good day.. There is this thing I would like to do in snippet (Sublime Text 3), something like this.

`<tabTrigger>CHOICE+VARIABLE</tabTrigger>`

so that when I trigger something like

CHOICE5

it would create a content like this.

...YOU TRIGGERED CHOICE 5...

Something like that,

I hope someone could help me with this. thanks in advance.

Comment: Close voters: From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [help], software questions are allowed if they cover *"[...] software tools commonly used by programmers".* Sublime Text, like Vim, Emacs, VSCode, etc., is a programming editor, and there are [tens of thousands of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim+or+vi+or+emacs+or+visual-studio-code) about them on this site that are perfectly on-topic.

Comment: Jason - what build are you using? You can find it under **`Help → About Sublime Text`**. Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and it is Build 4126